# NHibernate best practices (Query cache with much static data)

Tags: nhibernate, caching, query-cache

We have a situation, where we feel we do not fully take advantage of NHibernate's capabilities, which reduces performance. The actual situation is reduced to a "blogs with posts" example for this question.

A blog site, where each user can have its own blog which has an arbitrary number of posts. Therefore, there is a table for posts defined with the following columns:

```
id, blog_id, post_title, post_contents
```

Most blogs are rarely updated, while a few are "twitter-like" with frequent updates. There are many more reads than writes.

The front page of each blog displays the latest 5 entries.

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM blog_posts WHERE blog_id = ?
```

This will result in a number of elements being placed in both the 2nd level cache and query cache.

**Our problem is, that the cached query results for the blogs with 99%+ reads are destroyed because of the few blogs being updated frequently.**

How do you others usually solve this issue? What are the best practices?

Comment: Unless you know before querying the database which blogs are updated frequently ("twitter-like"), I think it will be very hard to devise a way to cache only the results of less frequently uppdated blogs...

Comment: Unfortunately, that can only be determined at runtime.
I was considering having a static dictionary of blog->posts in the logic code, and simply maintain this when adding/removing entries (With appropriate locking, of course). But this would just lead to issues if the site will someday be hosted on multiple servers.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an ASP.NET application? For this type of application, I would look into ASP.NET's page output caching capabilities before NHibernate's 2nd level cache.

Comment: I will look into that and reply then